# Cannot locate binary after rpm install

Tags: centos, rpm

I am dealing with a networking issue on my system and I wish to install `wireshark` to investigate the networking activity on it. The system uses `CentOS 7` and since I could not install it directly I downloaded the respective `rpm` files of `wireshark` along with its dependencies from the online repo ( http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7.9.2009/os/x86_64/Packages/ ) from another machine and transfered the files. After successfully installing the `wireshark rpm` file via

```
sudo rpm -ivh wireshark-1.10-14-25.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

I could not locate the binary file. Did I install a wrong `rpm` file or I did something wrong in a previous step?

Comment: What did you do to "locate" the file? Some shells cache filenames on the `PATH`, so you'd have to start it with explicit path (presumably `/usr/bin/wireshark`), or open a new terminal window, or use the entry in the "Network" section of your Desktop's app menu. (Maybe you also need wireshark-gnome to have a GUI at all, though.)

Comment: That's the thing. I did ```whereis wireshark``` and it replied with ```/usr/lib64/wireshark``` and ```/usr/share/wireshark```. No binary found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The misunderstanding may be in the naming. The package is named wireshark, but it [provides these binaries](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/wireshark-1.10.14-25.el7.x86_64.rpm.html):

```
/usr/sbin/capinfos
/usr/sbin/dftest
/usr/sbin/dumpcap
/usr/sbin/editcap
/usr/sbin/mergecap
/usr/sbin/randpkt
/usr/sbin/rawshark
/usr/sbin/reordercap
/usr/sbin/text2pcap
/usr/sbin/tshark
```

... none of which is named `wireshark`. You might want to start with `tshark`, but check out the [man pages](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/) for the other programs. The `/usr/sbin` directory may not be in your `PATH`, so you may need to use the full path (`/usr/sbin/tshark`) or add it to your PATH (`PATH=$PATH:/usr/sbin`).

If you're looking for the `wireshark` GUI program itself, that's provided by the [wireshark-gnome package](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/centos-x86_64/wireshark-gnome-1.8.10-25.el6.x86_64.rpm.html) in CentOS7.